# URI Save Password inside the link

Tags: bash, url, shell, passwords, uri

Is there a way to save the password of a ssh-connection inside an uri-link. AFAIK a uri can look like this username:password@domain/path. But the following example doesn't work on ubuntu:

```
ssh user:pass@domain/path
```

I always receive a "please enter password"-question. I know that it is not a quite secure way to save the password in plain text inside a link, but I have to work with other developers and what should I say... they are ex-Windows user, they don't like terminals and therefore I want to write a tiny shell script. this script should clone a remote git repo and create some specific stuff.

One click and I should do some magic!

Comment: That's not a URI, and/but SSH doesn't work with URIs anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a ssh-key generated with ssh-keygen (man ssh-keygen). This is also available on the windows platform within the putty environment.

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ssh./yourkeyfilewithoutpassphrase
ssh user@sshserver "your remote command"
```

Befor you can use your ssh-key in the remotehost, you must insert the public key to the authorized_keys file. A convenient way is the command

```
ssh-copy-id -i ssh./yourkeyfilewithoutpassphrase.pub user@sshserver
```

or, if the key is already loaded by the ssh-agent

```
ssh-copy-id user@sshserver
```

After this point, you dont need any password for ssh connection to established remote hosts. You should use per user a different ssh-key, so you are able to enable and disable keys without bothering the other users.

Answer (score 0):

You can't login with input password using ssh.
Another alternate way is setup a pair of ssh-keys, and login using ssh-key.
I follow the guide here: http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-ssh-no-password-without-any-private-keys-its-magi-1880.html